# Sequelize : how to create data with a nested table relationship using include

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I want to create nested table data using `User.create()` and `includes`. The table relationships are:

```
User.hasMany(models.Project, { onDelete: "CASCADE" });
User.hasMany(models.Task, { onDelete: "CASCADE" });
Project.belongsTo(models.User);
Project.hasMany(models.Task, { onDelete: "CASCADE" });
Task.belongsTo(models.User);
Task.belongsTo(models.Project);
```

This is what I have tried:

```
await models.User.create(
    {
      username: "un",
      projects: [
        {
          name: "project1",
          tasks: [
            {
              text: "task1",
            },
            {
              text: "task2",
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      include: [{ model: models.Project, include: [{ model: models.Task }] }],
    }
  );
```

But this is the generated SQL:

```
Executing (default): INSERT INTO "users" ("id","username","createdAt","updatedAt") VALUES (DEFAULT,$1,$2,$3) RETURNING *;
Executing (default): INSERT INTO "projects" ("id","name","deleted","createdAt","updatedAt","userId") VALUES (DEFAULT,$1,$2,$3,$4,$5) RETURNING *;
Executing (default): INSERT INTO "tasks" ("id","text","completed","deleted","createdAt","updatedAt","projectId") VALUES (DEFAULT,$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6) RETURNING *;
Executing (default): INSERT INTO "tasks" ("id","text","completed","deleted","createdAt","updatedAt","projectId") VALUES (DEFAULT,$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6) RETURNING *;
```

The problem is that it is missing the User:Task relationship on inserting the tasks. You can see that the tasks inserted were given an associated projectId, but not a userId. This has created an `a:b:c` relationship rather than the desired `a:b, b:c, a:c`

Comment: It seems you have some redundancy in your links. If a task belongs to a project and a project belongs to a user then there is no need to link a task and a user because they are linked through a project.

Comment: And I think Sequelize follows this rule to not duplicate parent keys on each level (it looks like a composite FK/PK)

Comment: @Anatoly, That makes sense. However, what if the tables are deeply nested (i.e. user > project > task > details > etc.) and I need to return the details for 1 task, but also need to make sure that it only returns the details for that task if it matches the userID making the request. Would I have to find the authenticated user, all their projects, all their tasks, and then the specific task details. It seems inefficient to me to have to return all the links in the chain just to ensure that the last link is related to the first link.

Comment: Then just query details for a certain taskId and include Task and Project model with only id attributes to add a condition for a userId in Project